# Java online Chess game

Tags: java, server

I want to make a chess online game in Java. I am able to write the game offline, that is no problem, but now I want to make it online so people can play over the internet.

Unfortunately i have no actual idea of how to do this so here are my questions:

- What kind of server do i need? (like webserver, xyz...?)
- How can i save the Chess board on a server?
- Do i have to make this with sockets and make it with the MVC? (so the client is a dumb buddy which only asks if this move is valid, if so it sends the info to the server which says yes/no and then makes the move and sends the new board to the clients again?
- Will i need Threads to make multiple instances of the boards on the server so multiple people can play at once?

Thanks to everyone showing the effort trying to help me! As you can see i am new to this and i do not know where to start, but i really want to make this!

Comment: too broad 
There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

Comment: This may be of some help:  https://github.com/Conductor/chess-web

Answer (score 1):

- You could set up a Tomcat server somewhere and put your programmed servlet there, but for you that may be a bit to much (either renting one or configurating one on a local machine). As an alternative one of your local PCs can just listen on a port, which is usually managed by the tool you use to communicate.
- The basics for loading and saving to disk are done with FileInputStream or FileOutputStream. It doesn't matter if your JVM is on your local PC or on a remote system. The advanced tricks are Serialization and APIs like Simple XML for Java.
- I'm not sure if I understand the question. If you're asking where the validation of the move should take place, that is personal taste, although I think it should take place on client and server. If you're asking how client and server should communicate, I think Remote Method Invocation (RMI) would be a good start for you. I came to love Akka, but I think that one is a little bit too much, but you can look into it, if you like. Sockets are to RMI and Akka what is going by foot to driving a bike or a car. It's good to understand communication, but not helpful for direct use in higher level programming (as in games).
- Each game could run in own thread, yes.

I think a good exercise for you would be to look up all words unknown to you from my answer, there is much to learn.

Comment: Although your answer is nice, off-topic questions should not be answered. It makes it harder to clean them up and might encourage further off-topic questions.

Comment: @ModusTollens Thanks for the clarification. I thought my note at the end of the post would be enough, but I understand.

Comment: No problem Another issue which just popped up: some people downvote answers to off-topic questions (I didn't).

Comment: @Ayutac pls, use an answer only for such, don't explain etiquette in it, that's what comments are for. since you cannot comment, please be patient earn reputation first, because that SO doesn't give you the privilege to comment on anything is not a flaw but a feature ;)

Comment: @WilliMentzel Thanks for the tip. However, that was a sincere attempt to gain rep :(

Comment: I think down votes should be cast on bad questions, not good solutions addressing on a bad question.

Comment: @user3437460 sounds like Konfuzius :D